# Joomla 1.6 Login from external application

Tags: php, joomla1.6

I am creating a website with single logon to WordPress, Joomla and Wiki. I am facing a problem with automatic login in Joomla. Can anyone help me with solution or source code for Joomla 1.6?

Thank You

Comment: How are you automating the wiki and wordpress?

Comment: I have created a simple login form and did the necessary change to Wiki and WP login pages. But same way is not possible in Joomla. Very difficulty to understand. If someone did this before, then it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how.

```
$app=JFactory::getApplication();

/* return Boolean */
$app->login(array('username'=>$data['login'], 'password'=>$data['pass']), array('silent'=>true)
```